# Why Promise is not displaying the data with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, es6-promise

I wrote a function to get a random number after 500 milliseconds and it worked perfectly with (`return new Promise (resolve,reject)`), also, it worked without it by using `setTimeout()` function, but when I added the promise and `setTimeout()` inside it wont show the result, I have `console.log()` before and after the result and both are showing. Please note that i am still new to the promise concept in general since this is a task from my coding school, thank you.

My code:

```
function getRandomNumber () {
   new Promise ((resolve,reject) =>{
      console.log('Getting Random Number...');
      let number =   Math.random();
      setTimeout( () => {
         if(number){
            resolve (`OK ${number}`);
            console.log('Done!');
         }
         else
            reject ('ERROR');
      }, 500);
   });   
 }
    
getRandomNumber();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You have no return from your function. you are just creating a promise and not calling it.

Comment: @MichaelMano isn't reslove() suppose to show me the result just like console.log(), or am I missing something?

Comment: Resolve is like the return of a function, it will return the data you pass it so you can use it in `.then` reject will return data that you can use in `.catch`

Comment: @MichaelMano oh, that make much more sense, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, return your promise, second use the result the promise provides either by creating a variable from it and awaiting it or using `then`

```js
function getRandomNumber() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Getting Random Number...');
        let number = Math.random();
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (number) {
                resolve(`OK ${number}`);
                console.log('Done!');
            } else {
                reject('ERROR');
            }
        }, 500);
    });

}

getRandomNumber().then(result => console.log(result));

(async () => {
  const number = await getRandomNumber();
  console.log(number);
 })();
```

Another option is to write `sleep` as a separate reusable function. Note `async` function can `await` multiple values and `return` values of their own. Calling an `async` function will **always** return a Promise -

```js
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

async function getRandomNumber() {
  console.log('Getting Random Number...')
  await sleep(500)
  const number = Math.random()
  console.log("Done!")
  return number
}

async function main() {
  const number1 = await getRandomNumber()
  console.log("number1", number1)
  const number2 = await getRandomNumber()
  console.log("number1", number2)
  const number3 = await getRandomNumber()
  console.log("number1", number3)
  return number1 + number2 + number3
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

```
Getting Random Number...
Done!
number1 0.2907058138817884
Getting Random Number...
Done!
number1 0.05784624607512423
Getting Random Number...
Done!
number1 0.889702848981964
1.2382549089388766
```

Comment: Thank you so much! , Its working now but the resolve says (Pending) before conslole.log('done) , any idea why it wont show the number? , or it wont until the setTimeout function finished, in my case after 500 milliseconds ?

Comment: I've updated my answer on `async` and `await` so you can do so without seeing the pending promise You can only use await inside of `async` functions, so ive put it inside of a self invoking function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise then you can use `await` inside `async` function to get the result

```js
function getRandomNumber () {
   return new Promise ((resolve,reject) =>{
      console.log('Getting Random Number...');
      let number =   Math.random();
      setTimeout( () => {
         if(number){
            resolve (`OK ${number}`);
            console.log('Done!');
         }
         else
            reject ('ERROR');
      }, 500);
   });   
 }
    
const printNumber = async () => console.log(await getRandomNumber());
printNumber();
```